# Why mongoTemplate is returning number type (int) column values are as doubles?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, mongotemplate

I am trying to get uniq account_numbers from the following document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5825e49785a4caf2bfa64a2f"),
    "profit" : "",
    "account_number" : 10,
    "m_number" : "",
    "registration_number" : "",
    "page_number" : "",
    "entry_date" : ISODate("2016-04-01T07:35:35Z"),
    "narration" : "By cash",
    "voucher_number" : "",
    "debit_credit" : 6150,
    "account_code" : 2102,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-04-01T07:35:35Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-04-01T07:35:35Z"),
    "employee_id" : 0,
    "balance" : 0,
    "credit" : 0,
    "debit" : 0,
    "particulars" : "",
    "since_last" : 0,
    "transaction_type" : 0,
    "voucher_path" : "",
    "branch" : "",
    "auto_voucher_number" : "",
    "check_book_series" : ""
}
```

The account_number type is number and I want to get it as int using Spring Mongo Template.

```
 Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("account_code").is(accountCode).and("account_number").exists(true));
    return List accounts = mongoTemplate.getCollection("transaction").distinct("account_number", query.getQueryObject());
```

Above code is returning List accounts. See debug results

```
 accounts = {ArrayList@6192}  size = 2815
 0 = {Double@6217} "1626.0"
 1 = {Double@6218} "1670.0"
 2 = {Double@6219} "2936.0"
 3 = {Double@6220} "2295.0"
 4 = {Double@6221} "1010.0"
 5 = {Double@6222} "1471.0"
 6 = {Double@6223} "3333.0"
 7 = {Double@6224} "1469.0"
 8 = {Double@6225} "3445.0"
 9 = {Double@6226} "3193.0"
 10 = {Double@6227} "219.0"
 11 = {Double@6228} "2509.0"
 12 = {Double@6229} "3750.0"
 13 = {Double@6230} "3425.0"
```

The short question is - how to get int type list from the document and why double types are returned ?

Here is the POJO for the document, may be I need to define something in the field ?

```
@Document(collection = "transaction")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Field(value = "id")
    private String id;

    @Field(value = "account_code")
    private Integer accountCode;

    @Field(value = "account_number")
    private Integer accountNumber;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default MongoDB saves numeric values as doubles:

For `db.coll.save({x: 1})` : `x` will be represented (and converted by your Java driver) as `1.0` double.

To insert a 32 bit integer, you must do:

`db.coll.save({x: NumberInt(1)})`

and for 64 integers, do:

`db.coll.save({x: NumberLong(1)})`

The underlying Java driver will also save `1` as double (I think) via `DBObject` or `Document`.

If you look carefully at your code:

`mongoTemplate.getCollection("transaction")`...

Here you are falling back to `DBCollection` which returns a raw list of the `account_number` which is , as said, represented as double by default. `MongoTemplate` mappings and conversions are no relevant here: these are used for entire documents (for example the `find` methods) which is not the case here.

In order to use `int` here, you will have to convert to `List` value yourself, or change the `account_number` storage values to `NumberInt`.